Can I operate a gas miner myself to mine gas or do I need a captain?
I have scoured through the tutorials, and read the entire command list twice and still am stumped: No command to operate the gas mining equipment is given anywhere. Is there really no way to operate a gas mining ship as the PC and you only can operate them to harvest gas by giving the ship to a hired captain?

Unfortunately it is impossible to manually harvest gas in the game.
Here is a link to the official X4 game manual that discusses this particular subject: https://wiki.egosoft.com:1337/X4%20Foundations%20Wiki/Manual%20and%20Guides/X4%3A%20Foundations%20Manual/Trading%20And%20Mining/#HManualNebulaMiningForLiquidResources
